# How do i float text next to images in HTML?

Tags: html

How do I insert text next to my images which are all on the left so the text is on the right going all the way down?

Comment: `float: right` your text? It's difficult to figure out what exactly you're asking for without showing any code.

Comment: <IMG SRC=”building.jpg” ALIGN=”left” />

Comment: It's hard to help you when you didn't give us any example what do you want to do. Show us your code

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/fV9srXE.png  https://i.imgur.com/3h2Tot1.png Basically the blank green bit i want to be able to write text over it without the text going through the image.

Answer (score 0):

You may make some ting like this

```
<div class="test">
   <span><img src="#"/></span>
   <span> text for image</span>
 </div>

<---css--->

 .test{
   display:flex,
   flex-direction:row
 }
```

and give the childrenn flex 1  they will be on the right just like you want

Comment: so where do i put this?

Comment: In the HTML  you have written with the content you want to display  pass variable if  you are getting data from some where